# Is there any way of navigation between community posts?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I had read some topics about community-wiki. I had found answers to most of my questions. May be I was bit lazy and other questions is already answered too?

1. As I understand, CW is an "improved FAQ" (yes?). But how can I find particular topic? For example, in last two weeks I saw some questions about function-based indexes (FBI) in Oracle RDBMS. Maybe there is a CW-post where using of FBI is clearly explained. I know I can use google search query like `function-based index oracle site:stackoverflow.com`, but is there a better way? In this case, I can just take link to such post and use it as answer and don't waste time. Also I would like to be sure, that if I didn't find nothing - it is because nothing exists.
2. Is there a way to see all CW posts (and only CW posts) related to particular topic (for example, oracle)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search for community-wiki posts *only* by adding `wiki:yes` to the search. Combine this with your keywords, or with tags (put those in square brackets).

For example, you can [search for all community-wiki `oracle`-tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+wiki%3Ayes+is%3Aq) (I added `is:q` to limit the search to questions).

However, Community Wiki is not a panacea, and searching for *just* CW posts is going to keep you from finding other great answers that are not marked as CW. People *can* make their post Community Wiki, but they don't *have* to.

I see [78 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+is%3Aq+function-based+index) when searching for `[oracle] is:q function-based index` for example; there could be gems among those posts that you'd miss if you limited yourself to Community Wiki only.

Comment: Thank you for answer. As you can see, I am new to stackoverflow community. I understand all that you say about CW, but I just want to look around and learn more about all available tools here.